# TMemData (TdxMemData) String type TField length truncated?

Tags: delphi

Data assigned to String type TMemData field truncates to 20 long. Help me understand why, I just started with TMemData, no experience with it.

```
procedure PopulateMemData(const Arr: TArray<TGasItem>; var mData: TdxMemData; var Grid: TcxGrid);
var
  I: Integer;
  MaxLenA: Integer;
  MaxLenB: Integer;
begin
  MaxLenA := 0;
  MaxLenB := 0;

// Creating here the fields dynamically

  CreateField(mData, 'ID',ftInteger);
  CreateField(mData, 'NameShort', ftString);
  CreateField(mData, 'NameLong', ftString);   <- data later added to this field is truncated 20 characters long.
  ...

// Data gets added


    mData.FieldByName('NameLong').AsString  := Arr[I].GetNameLong;
//    mData.FieldByName('NameLong').AsString  := 'sdfsdf sdf sdf sdf sdf wsdf sdf sdg sdg sdf sdg sdg sdg '; // Cuts length with this too

    mData.Post;

// Trying to figure out where the data disappears
    if Length(mData.FieldByName('NameLong').AsString) <> Length(Arr[I].GetNameLong) then ShowMessage('Different length on: ' + Arr[I].GetNameLong);
```

Anything longer than 20 characters is truncated to 20-long

Comment: Try Data.FieldByName('NameLong').size := 80; after creating field

Comment: Setting the size works, thanks. Now I need to try to find where it is preset to default to 20.

Comment: What does CreateField do exactly?

Comment: In Data.DB.pas the definition of `TStringField` has `property Size default 20;`.

Comment: @UweRaabe: It creates a field in the in-memory dataset, just like it does with a TClientDataSet.